# How to include a OSGI PlugIn into an Eclipse Project

Tags: java, plugins, frameworks, osgi, eclipse-luna

I'm using Eclipse Luna (64Bit) and I have to develop a System, which can manage several Plug-In's. The Plug-In's must be included at Runtime dynamically and I've read, that it is possible to do this with the OSGi-Framework. In Eclipse I started to implement some Example Plugin-Projects and now I want to include them into an another Eclipse Java-Project but thats over my head till now.

Is there a solution for this problem anyway or do I have to use another Framework?

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: What is your problem exactly? What have you tried so far? Read carefully the http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to write a plug-in for Eclipse or create your own plugin management system? If the latter, I'd suggest that you use OSGi as the basis instead of re-inventing the wheel. There's lots of good documentation on the 'net about how to do that.

Comment: We've got a system written in Java. An our task is, to develop software parts, which work as a plug-in for this system. These plug-ins should be .jar Files and must be added to the build-path at Runtime. I've read about including .jar Files in Java at Runtime and it's relative difficult.

Comment: Yes, you should build this on top of OSGi and not by trying to re-invent the wheel

Comment: Well, I've written a couple of books on Eclipse plug-in development :) But you can start by looking at the recipes on http://wiki.eclipse.org or http://wiki.osgi.org